# MYSQL count in conditions

Tags: mysql, count

I have this database and queries:

```
id  product_id  status
======================
1   25          1
2   25          1
3   25          0
4   26          1
etc.

$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM abc WHERE product_id = '25' AND status = '1'";
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM abc WHERE product_id = '25'";
```

Basically I need to count twice:

1. Count products with id=25 which has status=1, and
2. Count products with id=25

So, in returns I would like to have result:

There's **2** good items from **3** products

Is there a simple way to have this into single query?

[!] Sorry for bad explaination :p

Comment: Not tested since I don't have the data, but it could look like this: `SELECT COUNT(o.id) total, (SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM abc i WHERE i.product_id = o.product_id AND i.status = '1') AS total_active FROM abc o WHERE o.product_id = '25';`

Note: You probably use an integer (or a boolean if there's only two possibilities) for the status instead a string for the status ID and product ID.

Comment: @JonathanParentLevesque Great, it's work... Thx a lottt =)